# Find $f$ such that $xf(x)+x^2f(x-1)=f(x^2)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I found this functional equation: $$xf(x)+x^2f(x-1)=f(x^2)\tag1$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I tried to solve it (that is: find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that (1) is true); but I only found that $f(0)=0$ and classical substitution $x-1\mapsto x$ doesn't give me any information.

What do you think that can be a good approach?

Comment: I don't think this functional equation is unique... using plus one, minus 1, square, or square root can only generate countably number of numbers, where when considering about the reals, The real numbers can be classified using this method... so that's why I think this functional equation is not unique.

Comment: $f(x) = x(x+1)$ is a nontrivial solution. But I'm not sure how to find any others. (I found this one by noticing that if $f$ is differentiable, then $f(-1) = 0$.)

Comment: The solution set is a $\mathbb R$-vector space.

Comment: Yes, @KentaS. But now, what is an explicit basis for that vector space?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: (Assuming f(x) to be a polynomial)

Case 1:
If f(x) is a constant function,you will get $f(x)=0$.

Case 2:If f(x) is a non constant function,it has to be a quadratic function(which you can realize by assuming f(x) to be of degree n and comparing the degrees of LHS and RHS).

Also,you can assume your quadratic to be $ax^2+bx$.(as the c in standard quadratic function  $ax^2+bx+c$ will turn out to be $0$ if you plug $x=0$ in the equation.)

Comment: Why can you assume $f(x)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: You are assuming that $f$ is a polynomial

Comment: @KentaS  Oh yes,I was able to think of that only,I would edit my answer to make this clear.

Comment: I think this answer is a reasonably nice step towards a solution. +1

Comment: Just to complete: using the remark of @Ant (if $f$ is differentiable, then $f(-1)=0$), we get that the only polynomials solutions of (1) are of the form $ax(x+1)$.